# My programs stopped working

Tags: android, drawable

This is the part of my program that makes stop on working. Please help me.
is there some other way to make the Drawables load faster? I hope there is someone who can help me here. Just ask if you're interested. PLEASE. :(

```
Shuffle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int[] easy1 = {R.drawable.a11,R.drawable.a12,R.drawable.a13,R.drawable.a14,R.drawable.a15
                    ,R.drawable.a16,R.drawable.a17,R.drawable.a18,R.drawable.a19,R.drawable.a110
                    ,R.drawable.a111,R.drawable.a112,R.drawable.a113,R.drawable.a114,R.drawable.a115
                    ,R.drawable.a116,R.drawable.a117,R.drawable.a118,R.drawable.a119,R.drawable.a120
                    ,R.drawable.a121,R.drawable.a122,R.drawable.a123,R.drawable.a124}; 
    List<int[]> easy = new ArrayList<int[]>(easy1);
    Collections.shuffle(easy);
    iv1.setImageResource(easy1[0]);
    iv2.setImageResource(easy1[1]);
    iv3.setImageResource(easy1[2]);
    iv4.setImageResource(easy1[3]);
    iv5.setImageResource(easy1[4]);
    iv6.setImageResource(easy1[5]);
    iv7.setImageResource(easy1[6]);
    iv8.setImageResource(easy1[7]);
    iv9.setImageResource(easy1[8]);
    iv10.setImageResource(easy1[9]);
    iv11.setImageResource(easy1[10]);
    iv12.setImageResource(easy1[11]);
    iv13.setImageResource(easy1[12]);
    iv14.setImageResource(easy1[13]);
    iv15.setImageResource(easy1[14]);
    iv16.setImageResource(easy1[15]);
    iv17.setImageResource(easy1[16]);
    iv18.setImageResource(easy1[17]);
    iv19.setImageResource(easy1[18]);
    iv20.setImageResource(easy1[19]);
    iv21.setImageResource(easy1[20]);
    iv22.setImageResource(easy1[21]);
    iv23.setImageResource(easy1[22]);
    iv24.setImageResource(easy1[23]);
    iv25.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Post the Logcat error so we can help you.

Comment: Logcat part 1

01-22 00:08:55.474: E/AndroidRuntime(679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 00:08:55.474: E/AndroidRuntime(679): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=24; index=24
01-22 00:08:55.474: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at com.jepoy.Shift.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:107)
01-22 00:08:55.474: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-22 00:08:55.474: E/AndroidRuntime(679):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to randomize a list of numbers in a very inefficient way, which is possibly slowing your app down.

I suggest building an array of values 1 to 25, then just apply [Collections.shuffle(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) to get your random list.

Comment: I think so. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Am i doing it right? i have an error in "new Arraylist<int[]>(easy1);" see my edit

Comment: Remember that Java arrays are "zero-indexed". If your array is 24 elements long, you'll need to reference them with indices `easy1[0]` through `easy1[23]`. You'll get an error trying to use `easy1[24]` since that's attempting to use the 25th element in your easy1 array, giving you the error you pasted above.

Comment: i followed what you said. i still have an error in "new Arraylist<int[]>(easy1);"